# How to Move View up when Click on UITextField in CustomCell of UITableview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield, uiviewanimation

I have TextField in Custom Cell of UITableview .my Tableview is lower part of MainView so When i Click on TextField in CustomCell keyboard appear Which HIde my textfield.My below image show my problem

[image]

Here i have a Code which works when i have UITextField in MainView.please edit the Below Code Beacuse i want whole view Animation when i click on UITextfield.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField.tag > 0) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y-165.0,
                                 self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}   

   }
 -(void)textresign{

[[self.view viewWithTag:1]resignFirstResponder];
   }
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {         
if (textField.tag > 0) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view .frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+165.0,
                                  self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}   

  }
```

But i did't know how to Fix it for my Custom cell UITextField.Any help will be appriated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the code ,just need to change code little bit

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField.tag > 0)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y-165.0,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

use below method for repositioning the view on keyboard resigning instead of   `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField.tag > 0)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view .frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+165.0,
                                      self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

using below method it mandatory to set the delegate to the textfield.

i hope  you could get the solution.

Comment: thanks it works but the view never goes down after moving up.

Comment: @SHAZAD debug and check this `textFieldShouldReturn` method whether you get any call to this method whenever you try to resign keyboard.